# How to make the container padding responsive based on the content inside it?

Tags: javascript, css

Here, the image is responsive, can be multiple sizes and I want the padding-top of the container to be responsive to increase with the image size within it. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="container>
<img class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify ? what is the padding reference value to start from and what size of image would increase it (width,height,both)? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer would be to set media queries that match the ones the img is using. So, if the image has three sizes at 0-350 width, 351-760, 761+, you would need three media queries:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .container {
        padding-top: ...
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .container {
        padding-top: ...
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 761px) {
    .container {
        padding-top: ...
    }
}
```

If that doesn't suite you, then you'd likely need to know the img's height. CSS can't do that, but javascript can with [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight):

```js
const img = document.getElementByClassName('content').clientHeight;
```

Note that this will tell you how many pixels the "inner" part measures (actual height of element + padding but NOT border/margin).

After that, you'd be adding classes you've made with the appropriate padding, again with javascript.

so like:

```js
const img = document.getElementByClassName('content');
img.classList.add('whatever-specific-padding-class')
```

This is why I think the CSS/media query answer is probably better. You have to write separate classes anyway. Otherwise, you'd likely resort to inline styles which are no bueno.